# Using customized function in Python

Tags: python, list, function, dataframe

I am creating a function as follows:

```
def Player_stats(data,Template,Name,Competition):

    df_Player = data [(data['Player'] == Name) & (data['template'] == Template)]

    print(df_Player.head())


    return df_Player
```

The input to the function is data (dataframe), Template(String), Name (string), Competition (String).

Below is how I call the function:

```
Template ='ACCURACY'
Competition = 'England. Premier League'
Name = 'P. Pogba'
df = Player_stats (DF_new,Name,Template,Competition)
```

The issue is when I call the function, it shows empty data frame.

If I just insert the exact string in the function as follow:

```
def Player_stats(data,Template,Name,Competition):

    df_Player = data [(data['Player'] == 'P. Pogba') & (data['template'] == 'ACCURACY')]

    print(df_Player.head())

    return df_Player
```

It shows me the data frame. However, I want to call the function using different inputs.

Every time, I use variable such as Name, Competition, Template, it always shows empty data frame.

Comment: Is it significant that you've reversed the Template and Name strings?

Comment: OMG. How come I didn’t notice that.

Comment: Thanks. A lot. Appreciate the spot on my mistake

Comment: Variable and function names should follow the `lower_case_with_underscores` style.

Comment: This question may be closed as Typo/Unrepro.

Answer (score 0):

Please check if your column names in dataframe are correct when you are calling it to your function. Update data['Player'] to data.Player

```
def Player_stats(data,Template,Name,Competition):

    df_Player = data [(data.Player == Name) & (data.template == Template)]

    print(df_Player.head())


    return df_Player
```